# How to stop consuming message from selective queue - RabbitMQ - Javascript/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am building a REST-amqp sample in which I get messages from a given queue in rabbitmq and I send the messages back to the client via REST.

I have implemented the code following rabbitmq tutorial for node.js

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://192.168.225.203:5672', function (err, conn) {
conn.createChannel(function (err, ch) {
    var q = 'aQueue';
    ch.assertQueue(q, { durable: false });
    var messages = [];
    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
    ch.consume(q, function (msg) {
        console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
        messages.push(msg.content.toString());
        messages.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(element);
        });
    }, { noAck: true });
});
```

});

I can consolidate all messages in an array (messages) but this function runs till the application is stopped, which is not a good thing as the REST client will wait forever....
I would like to stop the function and move on with the program when the queue is empty or after a period of time (2secs) if the first option is not possible.
I found the same problem solved in Java but not in JS.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Cheers, Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`connection#close`](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#model_close) to stop the connection altogether and build up a new one on-demand.

However, you still need to detect *when* to terminate the connection.

May I ask what exactly the motivation behind this is? HTTP/REST and message queues are inherently different. Sending a message based on an HTTP request is one thing; receiving message for a certain request is definitely a place I would not go voluntarily.

Comment: Thanks Mate, yeah... the 'when' could be time based or when queue is empty. I still have the problem of 'how'. setInterval and setTimeout are asynchronous so even if I place a 'return' in that function wouldn't work on my one.

On the philosophical reason behind this, I agree with you, this is a technology demonstration , more than a real case scenario.

Comment: I suggest using Promises for this endeavor. It's a lot easier to manage operation(s) and you can bail at a specific point with a well defined escape path (reject the promise or throw an exception, add a `.catch` disconnecting).